# JSF 2.0 h:inputText inside ui:repeat

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

How I should change following example that after changes values in inputText not disappears after commandButton was submitted? I'm understanding why it happens, but I don't know how to fix it.

```
<h:form>
    <h:selectOneMenu valueChangeListener="#{foo.selectChanges}" onchange="submit()" >
        <f:selectItem itemValue="5" itemLabel="Five"/>
        <f:selectItem itemValue="10" itemLabel="Ten"/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>

    <ui:repeat value="#{foo.repeatItems}" var="item">
        <div>
            <h:inputText value="#{item.value}"/>
        </div>
    </ui:repeat>

    <h:commandButton value="test" action="#{foo.submit}">
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

And bean:

```
public class FooBean {

    private RepeatItem[] repeatItems;

    private String value = "5";

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(final String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void submit() {

    }

    public void selectChanges(ValueChangeEvent e) {
        value = (String) e.getNewValue();
    }

    public RepeatItem[] getRepeatItems() {
        repeatItems = new RepeatItem[Integer.parseInt(value)];

        for (int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(value); i++) {
            repeatItems[i] = new RepeatItem();
        }

        return repeatItems;
    }

    public void setRepeatItems(final RepeatItem[] repeatItems) {
        this.repeatItems = repeatItems;
    }

    public static class RepeatItem {

        private String value;

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(final String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd like to put the bean in the `view` scope to keep it alive in subsequent requests to the same view. You'd also like to prefill in the `valueChangeListener` method instead of the getter method since a getter method is called multiple times in JSF's lifecycle and is actually supposed to only *return* the data. You would also like to use `f:ajax` here to improve user experience by partial submits instead of submitting the whole page by Javascript's `submit()`. Here's a kickoff example:

XHTML:

```
<h:form>
    <h:selectOneMenu valueChangeListener="#{bean.prefill}" converter="javax.faces.Integer">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="0" itemLabel="Please select" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="5" itemLabel="Five"/>
        <f:selectItem itemValue="10" itemLabel="Ten"/>
        <f:ajax event="change" render="items" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <h:panelGroup id="items">
        <ui:repeat value="#{bean.items}" var="item">
            <div><h:inputText value="#{item.value}"/></div>
        </ui:repeat>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{bean.submit}" />
    <h:messages />
</h:form>
```

Bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean {

    private List<Item> items;

    public void prefill(ValueChangeEvent event) {
        Integer count = (Integer) event.getNewValue();
        items = new ArrayList<Item>();
        while (count-- > 0) items.add(new Item());
    }

    public void submit() {
        System.out.println(items);
    }

    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }    

}
```

Item:

```
public class Item {

    private String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

#### See also:

- [Why JSF calls getters multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times/2090062#2090062)
- [The benefits and pitfalls of `@ViewScoped`](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2010/06/benefits-and-pitfalls-of-viewscoped.html)

Comment: Thanks, I copy pasted your example, but during ajax call I receive this exception: https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1EdbQ_CLnczMqpfBSc7F4LGRJI8dbEJwa74RrGVsCpjk Maybe again something wrong with my JSF version?

Comment: Check server startup logs, probably something failed to initialize. Note that with a default JSF 2.0 install without any component libraries, the `web.xml` is supposed to contain **only** the `FacesServlet` definition. Probably there's some noise leftover from previous older/wrong implementations/libraries.